# Multiple effects causing extra phases in M:tG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Just checking that I understand rule 500.8 correctly:

> 500.8. Some effects can add phases to a turn. They do this by adding the phases directly after the specified phase. If multiple extra phases are created after the same phase, the most recently created phase will occur first.

If multiple effects add extra phases before the current ones is over, these phases will run one after the other, right? If [Medomai the Ageless](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Medomai%20the%20Ageless) attacks alone while [Finest Hour](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Finest%20Hour) is on the battlefield and then deals damage, I'll get two extra combat phases?

---

ETA:

Obviously I had a big brainfart, but I guess the question was answered anyway. For a more practical example with extra turns, it's safe to assume that if I connect with both Medomai and [Wanderwine Prophets](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wanderwine%20Prophets) (and sacrifice a merfolk), I'll get two extra turns?

Comment: Did you maybe mean something like Aurelia? Medomai gives an extra turn, not a combat phase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Medomai adds turns, not phases, so the rule you quoted isn't really necessary. Assuming no blockers, here's what happens:

- Medomai attacks on your turn. Finest Hour's abilities trigger.
- You can stack Finest Hour's abilities in either order. Assuming no other actions, Medomai is now 5/5 and there is now a combat phase after the current combat phase.
- Medomai deals damage. Medomai's ability triggers, so you take an extra turn after this one.
- You get another combat phase. Medomai attacks again, gaining another Exalted trigger.
- Medomai deals damage. Medomai triggers and you get another turn after this one (and before the other extra turn, not that it matters)
- You take two consecutive turns in which Medomai can't attack. Each of those turns can get a bonus combat phase from Finest Hour if you have non-Medomai creatures to attack with.

Comment: The reason that the placement of the second extra turn matters is that an opponent could steal control of or more commonly  copy Medomai's triggered ability. I can't think of a card that does this off of the top of my head, though.

Comment: @John well yeah, basically anything could matter if you stipulate the presence of a card that will make it matter. A more pertinent example might be if someone activates Mindslaver between the two combat steps.

Comment: On the contrary, anything could *not* matter if you stipulate the *absence* of relevant cards from your opponent. Rather than add another assumption to the beginning of a false statement to make it true, why not remove the false statement?

Comment: @John: It's a reasonable default assumption that cards not explicitly mentioned are absent. Last I checked the test to become a *judge* operates under this assumption.

Comment: Last I checked, there is no question on the judge's test like "You have an Elvish mystic on the board and your opponent is at 20 life. Do you win?" The absence of relevant cards does not imply absolute uselessness of placing extra turns in the correct order. Elvish Mystic wins games single-handedly, assuming you have nothing relevant to play. Is this information useful? No.

Comment: @John: As I recall, however, there were plenty of questions along the lines of "You have X Grizzly Bears in play and your opponent casts Pyroclasm. How big is your Lhurgoyf?" And no one feels the need to preface every "You would win the game" with "unless you have Abyssal Persecutor" in play. The specific cards mentioned to not care in what order OP takes the extra turns. And I even specifically mentioned what order the turns are in despite it not generally mattering, so the reader can easily extrapolate for a different game state when it does matter.

Comment: Next time I am taking a judge test and I answer the question "*You have X Grizzly Bears in play and your opponent casts Pyroclasm. How big is your Lhurgoyf?*", I will respond, "*My Lhurgoyf is (X)/(1+X), not that it matters.*" I hope I get bonus points for actually answering the question, despite it generally not mattering.

Comment: @John In this case the order of the 2 turns is irrelevant. It has no outcome on the game state absent some intervention. In the example you just gave, the power of the creature is always a relevant part of the game state.

Comment: @Cruncher You are wrong. Changes in power or toughness are *not* a relevant part of the game state. To quote an actual judge, "Visible game state includes life totals, the zone of any object, whether an object is tapped, but does not include giant growth type effects, nor abilities that a creature may lose or gain." - fistofthor, LV1 Judge (http://www.reddit.com/r/mtgjudge/comments/1a9m5o/thinking_thursday/)

Comment: @John the question is EXPLICITLY asking you for the p/t of the Lhurgoyf. How can it not be relevant to that question? that IS the question.

Comment: @Cruncher I was simply applying Chad Miller's logic to other situations. According to Chad, in the absence of a card that makes it relevant, the power and toughness of a creature must not be relevant. We are saying the exact same thing, except that YOU both feel the need to put "it doesn't matter" next to everything that doesn't matter, while I feel that it is extraneous and inconsistent with the remainder of the answer.

Comment: @Cruncher For example, "You can stack Finest Hour's abilities in either order". Why not tack on a "not that it matters" clause? Absent some intervention, it does not matter, and yet we didn't really have to say that, did we?

Comment: @John: "YOU both feel the need to put "it doesn't matter" next to everything that doesn't matter" Now you're just making things up.

Comment: @ChadMiller Which part was made up?

Comment: Order of extra turns matters if not all of your extra turns are the same, such as the extra turn created by Final Fortune (which, unlike a regular extra turn, you lose the game at the end of).